# Regular expression for decimal followed by string

Tags: regex, string, numbers

I need a regular expression that matches the following examples

```
251.51 Kb
232.113 Mb
35 ss
 325.10323 sd
  23    hhh
33ffg
```

So, basically any decimal number followed by 1 alphabetic string only. Spaces ignored between these 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex would be,

```
^\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*[a-zA-Z]+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jV9lQ9/1)

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `\s*` Matches Zero or more spaces.
- `\d+` Matches one or more numbers.
- `(?:\.\d+)?` Optional one or more number preceded by a dot.
- `\s*` Matches Zero or more spaces.
- `[a-zA-Z]+` Matches one or more alphabets.
- `$` End of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(\s+)?[a-zA-Z])
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sU3bY4/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
^\s*((?:\d+\.\d+)|(?:\d+))(?:\Z|\D)
```

[See it work](http://regex101.com/r/lN5yM6/1)

Or, if you only want to match a numeric only if followed by letter or spaces then letters:

```
^\s*((?:\d+\.\d+)|(?:\d+))(?:\s*[a-zA-Z])
```

[See that one](http://regex101.com/r/fL3gX1/2)